# how to commit a transaction in EJB?

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

I have the following scenario,

```
public void someEjbMethod1()
{
    for (int i=0; i=10; i++)
    {
        em.merge(arr[i]);
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

I need to merge each object of (`arr[i]`) separately. as the above code will commit all the `arr[i]` instances at the end of the function.

I am thinking to do the following:

```
public void someEjbMethod1()
{
    for (int i=0; i=10; i++)
    {
        saveObj(arr[i]);
    }
}

// should I use a transaction attribute here??
public void saveObj(SomeObject obj)
{
    em.merge(arr[i]);
    em.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want container managed transactions, you may use the @TransactionAttribute with the value  [TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#REQUIRES_NEW) to annotate the `saveObj` method as:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void saveObj(SomeObject obj)
{
    ...
}
```

This will ensure that a new transaction will be started for every invocation of the `saveObj` method. The existing transaction associated with the `someEjbMethod` will be suspended before every invocation of the `saveObj` method. Every transaction started for the `saveObj` method will be committed on return, and hence every entity will be updated in the database in it's own transaction.

Comment: What do you mean by "still don't work"? Does transaction creation fail on every invocation or something else? Also, consider enabling finer debugging of the JTA co-ordinator; you will be able to determine whether a new transaction is being started or not.

Comment: I mean, the database don't get updated on each exit of `saveObj` however, in the app server log, the update sql query got printed

Comment: What JPA provider are you using? If you are using EclipseLink, have you integrated the provider with the [JTA transaction manager of OC4J](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Integrating_EclipseLink_with_an_Application_Server_(ELUG)#Integrating_EclipseLink_with_Oracle_Containers_for_J2EE_.28OC4J.29)?

Comment: I am using oc4j 10.1.3.4 as EJB container and its bundled toplink as JPA implementation.

Comment: I can think of one possible reason - is there a `ejb-jar.xml` or `orion-ejb-jar.xml` file whose entries would override the annotation? Usually, the container uses the attributes declared in the annotations, unless there is a deployment descriptor that describes the values. In the event of a conflict, the values in the deployment descriptor take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

You can request a UserTransaction, have a look [here](http://geertschuring.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/how-to-use-bean-managed-transactions-with-ejb3-jpa-and-jta/) for some inspiration.